# sort&compress is Not Working

Tags: natbib

Can someone explain why in the code below sort&compress is not working? What is the solution?

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,10pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,epstopdf,newlfont,graphicx,subfigure,booktabs}
\PassOptionsToPackage{sort&compress}{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
%
\begin{document}
%
\section{*}
bla bla bla \cite{carnicer2010weighted,wang2010rational,bos2013bounding}. 

\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\bibliography{Bib}
\end{document}
```

You can use the below bibliography:

```
@article{carnicer2010weighted,
  title={Weighted interpolation for equidistant nodes},
  author={Carnicer, Jesus M},
  journal={Numerical Algorithms},
  volume={55},
  number={2},
  pages={223--232},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@article{wang2010rational,
  title={A rational interpolation scheme with superpolynomial rate of convergence},
  author={Wang, Qiqi and Moin, Parviz and Iaccarino, Gianluca},
  journal={SIAM Journal on Numerical Analysis},
  volume={47},
  number={6},
  pages={4073--4097},
  year={2010},
  publisher={SIAM}
}

@article{bos2013bounding,
  title={Bounding the {L}ebesgue constant for {B}errut’s rational interpolant at general nodes},
  author={Bos, Len and De Marchi, Stefano and Hormann, Kai and Sidon, Jean},
  journal={Journal of Approximation Theory},
  volume={169},
  pages={7--22},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

The updated code is as follows:

    \listfiles
\PassOptionsToPackage{numbers,sort&compress}{natbib}
\documentclass[final,3p,times,10pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,epstopdf,newlfont,graphicx,subfigure,booktabs}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
%
\begin{document}
%
\section{*}
bla bla bla \cite{carnicer2010weighted,wang2010rational,bos2013bounding}. 

\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\bibliography{Bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to try using `sort&compress` as an option of the document class: `\documentclass[final,3p,times,10pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}` should result in the expected output.

Comment: the package is already loaded, so `\PassOptionsToPackage` does nothing.

Comment: @leandriis wouldn't it also work to move `\PassOptionsToPackage{sort&compress}{natbib}` up before `\documentclass`? The placement in the MWE is clearly wrong as it is after `natbib` has been loaded

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what about moving it before `\documentclass`? (untested)

Comment: @daleif that should work (if elsarticle really loads).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer just tested it, works on TL22

Comment: I tried all ideas above but with no success.

Comment: A somewhat marginal comment: If you use `\documentclass{elsarticle}` to submit to Elsevier, you probably should not fiddle around with their intended citation style. If you are not planning to submit to Elsevier, why use this highly specialised class instead of, e.g. `\documentclass{article}` or `\documentclass{scrartcl}`?

Comment: @Manuel Weinkauf nice remark. However, I often submit most of my works to Elsevier.

Answer (score 2):

`elsarticle` auto loads `natbib` so your placement of

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{sort&compress}{natbib}
```

is too late, the package is already loaded at that point.

If you move it above `\documentclass`, then it works

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{sort&compress}{natbib}
\documentclass[final,3p,times,10pt]{elsarticle}
```

Alternatively (as @leandriis mentioned) you can also pass it as a class option

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,10pt,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
```

that also works

Comment: I tried them both but the problem still persists. Something else is causing LaTeX to ignore these options. I'm using Texmaker 5.1.2 BTW. My Miktex Console is set to retrieve packages from Random package repository on the Internet.

Comment: @Dr.KareemElgindy  Then update your question with a log file of your compilation of the example (the log file from disk, not the filtered log that TeXMaker shows). Note that TeXMaker has nothing do do with this. It runs just fine on my TeXLive 2022.

Comment: I'm not that good, so could you point to where exactly can I find such a file?

Comment: @Dr.KareemElgindy when you compile your document, besides the PDF there is also a `.log`, this is a text file. You can open it with TeXMaker. Update your question with the contents of this file.

Comment: @dalief see https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UDmSCbyEaIp9fsKub4Un5g1ZF3Dxbadq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Dr.KareemElgindy please update your question with this data. Links rot over time and thus it cannot help others. Plus I cannot see it without being logged in, sorry, not going there.

Comment: @dalief I tried but I got the error message 
Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 45252. Should I truncate the file?

Comment: @Dr.KareemElgindy hmm, expl3 is making these massive. You can cut all the `LaTeX Font Info: ` lines

Comment: @Dr.KareemElgindy Alternatively you can just place `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` this list all version numbers in the log, then update your question with that list.

Comment: @dalief I added the truncated log file above.

Comment: @Dr.KareemElgindy seems normal. That exactly do you see in the output that makes you thing it does not work?

Comment: @dalief The Refs. appear as [1, 2, 3] rather than [1-3].

Comment: @Dr.KareemElgindy and you tried running pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex in your TeXMaker? It seems we have the same versions, and it *is* the exact example your are now testing where the `\PassOptionsToPackage{sort&compress}{natbib}` has been moved before `\documentclass`? You could replace the log in the question with the updated example your are now using. **do not delete the original example!!!** otherwise the discussion, comments and answer does not make sense.

Comment: @dalief I added the updated code.

Comment: @Dr.KareemElgindy as far as I can see you did not add any updated code, only deleted the log.

Comment: @dalief you have been very cooperative with me. I largely appreciate the time you took to analyze my problem, but to tell you the truth. I gave up... it seems my problem has no solution :-(

Comment: @Dr.KareemElgindy well it works for everyone else, so you'll have to find someone who can physically help you. I still would like to see exactly what updated code you're using that does not work.